# Resize Chart PlotArea below Chart Title

Tags: excel, vba, resize, bar-chart

I am trying to resize a Clustered Bar Chart PlotArea (along with Primary XValue Axis on the top) to dynamically align just below the Chart Title. However, i am not able to change the Top & Height of the Plot Area based on the ChartTitle.Top & ChartTitle.Height. The Chart does not have legends and its Primary XValue Axis is on top and Primary Category Axis on the Left. This is how the Chart looks:

[image]

The data for the Chart is like this:

```
Col A                                                                     Col B
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.                    5
Vestibulum malesuada nisl condimentum, venenatis dolor id, commodo lectus.  3
Vivamus imperdiet dolor quis massa tincidunt, sed hendrerit metus maximus.  2
Donec ut ligula vulputate, eleifend massa vel, tincidunt magna.             2
Mauris molestie purus non eros egestas interdum.                            1
Sed auctor eros non nunc porta, id lacinia mi ultricies.                    1
```

This is a snippet of the code:

```
With myChart.Chart
    With .PlotArea
        .Select
        .Top = myChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Top + myChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Height
        .Height = myChart.Height - .Top
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlotArea` has a `Position` property that could be set to `xlChartElementPositionAutomatic`

```
VBA value: -4105
```

This resizes the title and the plot area perfectly.

[MSDN info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.xlchartelementposition?view=office-pia)

Comment: Excellent! @EylM this was right under my eye and so easy. But i tried only the `xlChartElementPositionCustom` option. Thanks a bunch!